# Read file character by character and test using <cctype>

Tags: c++, file, character

I'm trying to read from a file and keep a total of how many uppercase letters there are and then output the number of uppercase letters in the file. I am trying to read the file character by character and when it encounters an uppercase letter, store it in a variable, for instance: char, and then output the total in the variable but when I go to run my code, I keep getting the first uppercase letter of the file being output multiple times.

I tried to use (isupper(character)) in a loop to keep track of each uppercase letter but whenever I went to run my code, I was outputting an upside down question mark. I tried taking the loop out just to see if I can at least get isupper to count the first capital letter and output "1". This is when I see the first lowercase letter of the file being output. Before I tried isupper, I made sure that I could at least output my file in its entirety which I was able to.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream inputFile;
  inputFile.open("text.txt");

  if (!inputFile)
  {
    cerr << "Unable to open file text.txt";
    exit(1); // call system to stop
  }

  if (inputFile.is_open())
  {
    char character=0;
    int total = 0;

    inputFile.get(character);

    while (inputFile)
    {
        while (isupper(character))

        inputFile >> character;
        total += character;
        cout << character;
    }


    inputFile.close();
  }



  return 0;
}
```

When I use isupper I get the first lowercase letter of the file outputted multiple times and when I use islower I get the first uppercase letter of the file. I should be seeing the uppercase letter totals for isupper and the lowercase letter totals for islower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the inner `while` loop. What you need is just a single `if (isupper(character))` statement that would increase the counter whenever the next character is uppercase. One more problem is that you increase the `total` by the value of ASCII code of the character.

Try this:

```
    while (inputFile)
    {
        if (isupper(character))
        {
            ++total;
            cout << character;
        }

        inputFile >> character;
    }
    cout << total;
```

By the way, due to incorrect formatting your program is misleading. If you correct the formatting you would probably find your problem:

```
        while (inputFile)
        {
            while (isupper(character))
                inputFile >> character;
            total += character;
            cout << character;
        }
```

Comment: A slightly more idiomatic way to write the outer loop would be `while (inputFile >> character)`. That also removes the need to read the character once before entering the loop.

Comment: @PeteBecker I guess that it is better to minimize the diff with the author's code when you are explaining his mistakes.

Comment: The above works to output all the uppercase letters in the file but my problem is getting the code to output an integer number for the actual number of uppercase letters there are. I get stuck on trying to use a loop and a counter to count the total because I am having a hard time conceptualizing the correlation between the letters and numbers. For instance, if I wanted to use a for loop, I don't understand the conditions I would need. I wanted to do something like this: for (int count = 0; count < size; count++) but am confused about what to use in place of size to tell the loop when to end.

Comment: No, when I do that it does the same thing as my original code except it outputs a bunch of numbers. It looks like an infinite loop which is why I was trying to use a loop to tell the code when to stop outputting but since the file is characters, not numbers, I don't know how to get that to correspond to something like size if that makes sense.

Comment: Ok I understand what I did wrong with total. I had total and cout<<total in the wrong portion of my loop.Once I changed it, I was able to output the total and the uppercase letters. However, I didn't need to actual letters themselves to be ouput so I just deleted cout<<character portion and outputted just the total. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also make life easier if you need to capture the lower-case and upper-case characters from the file by simply saving the lower and upper case characters to separate `std::vector<char>`. For example:

```
#include <vector>
...
    std::vector<char> lower, upper;
```

Then you can open and read from your file classifying your characters and adding the lower-case characters to your `lower` vector and upper-case to your `upper` vector. Storage is automatically allocated, and your total is the size of each vector when you are done (e.g. the number of lower-case characters will be `lower.size()`) You can read, classify and store the characters as follows:

```
    char c;
    std::vector<char> lower, upper;
    std::ifstream f (argv[1]);

    while (f >> c) {
        if (islower(c))
            lower.push_back(c);
        else if (isupper(c))
            upper.push_back(c);
    }
```

That's it, you have now captured all lower-case characters and all upper-case characters and you have the count of each. You can output all information with:

```
    std::cout << "Total lower + upper: " << lower.size() + upper.size() << 
            "\n\nlower: ";
    for (auto& l : lower)
        std::cout << " " << (char)l;

    std::cout << "\n(" << lower.size() << "-chars)\n\nupper: ";

    for (auto& u : upper)
        std::cout << " " << (char)u;

    std::cout << "\n(" << upper.size() << "-chars)\n";
```

(**note:** the use of a [Range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to loop over each character in each vector)

Putting together a complete example, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "error: filename required as argument.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    char c;
    std::vector<char> lower, upper;
    std::ifstream f (argv[1]);

    while (f >> c) {
        if (islower(c))
            lower.push_back(c);
        else if (isupper(c))
            upper.push_back(c);
    }

    std::cout << "Total lower + upper: " << lower.size() + upper.size() << 
            "\n\nlower: ";
    for (auto& l : lower)
        std::cout << " " << (char)l;

    std::cout << "\n(" << lower.size() << "-chars)\n\nupper: ";

    for (auto& u : upper)
        std::cout << " " << (char)u;

    std::cout << "\n(" << upper.size() << "-chars)\n";
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/lowerupper.txt
aAbBcCdDeEfFgG
123
hHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpP
<-->
qQrRsStTuUvV;
wWxXyYzZ
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/lowerupper dat/lowerupper.txt
Total lower + upper: 52

lower:  a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
(26-chars)

upper:  A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
(26-chars)
```